# What is the single best feat to raise my druid's CMD, other than Defensive Combat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, druid, combat-maneuver

I'm a druid looking to select just one feat to boost my CMD. No level restrictions. I have found Defensive Combat Training but is there anything that increases CMD even more?

Comment: Not a duplicate; this one is about CMD, the other question is about CMB.

Comment: Ah, right, CM**B** and CM**D**. My bad.

Comment: [Related] [How can I improve my Druid build's inherent CMB, mostly for use during Wild Shaping?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/96679)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned, [Defensive Combat Training](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/defensive-combat-training-combat/) lets you treat your BAB as your HD when calculating CMD. Useful for non-full-BAB classes at higher levels.

[Advanced Defensive Combat Training](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Advanced%20Defensive%20Combat%20Training) gives you a +4 untyped bonus to CMD, but requires membership in a specific faction (and 10 TPA in said faction). Your GM may not allow this feat. Unfortunately this feat also requires Defensive Combat Training, and you stated a need for only *one* feat.

[Coordinated Defense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/coordinated-defense-combat-teamwork/) is a teamwork feat that gives you +2 to CMD if you're adjacent to an ally with the same feat. For a druid this is less useful than just taking Defensive Combat Training, if your character level is 5 or more.

Also be sure to keep this in mind:

> **Miscellaneous Modifiers**
>   A creature can also add any circumstance, deflection, dodge, insight, luck, morale, profane, and sacred bonuses to AC to its CMD. Any penalties to a creature’s AC also apply to its CMD. A flat-footed creature does not add its Dexterity bonus to its CMD.

So even feats like Dodge can be helpful since they increase both your AC and your CMD.

If there's a specific combat maneuver you're afraid of, that could give your more options. For example, and this is a common fear for spellcasters, grappling. A cheap and surprisingly effective way to counter grappling is a *wand of grease*. A wand can be activated while grappled, doesn't provoke an AoO, and *grease* gives a hefty +10 bonus to CMB/CMD to avoid being grappled.

#### Bottom line?

Defensive Combat Training is the "single best" feat for this purpose, yes.